# file route in a shared directory is not working as expected - apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I've a camel route defined like the following:

```
from("file:" + this.notificationsFileDropPath + "/?fileName=notifications.csv" +
            "&preMove=inprogress" +
            "&move=processed")
        .routeId("notifications.readcsv")
                .unmarshal().csv()
  .to("direct:notifications-parsing");
```

The above route is not working(getting stuck) when "notificationsFileDropPath" is a shared folder: meaning my route is active on 2 different machines but the shared folder is common for both. I tried to use the readLock options mentioned in the camel documentation but that didn't help either. Any clues on how to make this work?

Comment: You surely have seen this on (http://camel.apache.org/file2):Avoid reading files currently being written by another application
Beware the JDK File IO API is a bit limited in detecting whether another application is currently writing/copying a file. And the implementation can be different depending on OS platform as well. This could lead to that Camel thinks the file is not locked by another process and start consuming it. Therefore you have to do you own investigation what suites your environment. To help with this Camel provides different readLock options and doneFileName... (continued)

Comment: Can you check the permissions of the shared folder? Give full permission and try.

Comment: Using a marker file is probably the way to go. As Sumeet said, your consumer routes would need write permissions in the directory they are reading. (If they do not have that, you'll need to consider an idempotentRepository that supports clustering.)

Comment: @SumeetPatil Of course, they do have permissions.

Comment: You should be able to lock the file and once locked the file consumer will not consume it.